# Existe algum lugar onde podemos ver perguntas que foram fechadas?

Tags: suporte

As perguntas fechadas são excluídas ou existe algum lugar que possam ser encontradas ?

Comment: Já tentou utlizar na pesquisa o coringa [closed:yes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes)?

Comment: uia nem sabia...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perguntas fechadas não são excluídas, a não ser que não tenha upvotes em uma resposta ou na pergunta e não tenha uma resposta aceita.

- Para encontrar perguntas fechadas digite na busca [`closed:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed:yes)
- Para encontrar perguntas deletadas digite [`deleted:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted:yes) (só é possível ver as suas próprias postagens)
- Existe um tipo de pesquisa especifica para perguntas duplicatas, basta digitar [`duplicate:yes`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate:yes)

Existe também uma maneira de buscar se é questão ou uma resposta `is:question` e `is:answer`, você pode combinar eles com `deleted:yes`, assim:

- [deleted:yes is:question](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes%20is%3Aquestion)
- [deleted:yes is:answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes%20is%3Aanswer)

Para ver mais maneiras de pesquisa clique em *Pesquisa Avançada*:

> [image: pesquisa avançada]